# Stop the event datepicker in Extjs

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I have a problem with datepicker (Ext.picker.Date) on Extjs. When i select a date in the datepicker i need verify if a store XXX have changes. I check this with the boolean storeChanged, then if the store have changes i need **stop** the select event. How I can do this?

My current code is:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.ActivityController', {

extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: [
    'App.view.panels.ManagedActivity'
],

storeChanged: false,

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'ManagedActivity > panel > datepicker': {
            select: this.onSelectDatepicker
        }
    });
},

onSelectDatepicker: function(datepicker, date) {

    if(this.storeChanged) {

        var store = this.getGridActivity().getStore();
        store.load({
            params: {
                date: Ext.Date.format(date, 'd-m-Y').toString()
            }
        });
    } else {

        // how stop the event ??
    }

},
```

});

Comment: Usually returning false from an event handler will stop it.

In this case, when the select event fires, the value selected has already been stored in the date field.

Comment: then i think it not possibly on this way, then i need save the current state and after restore.